# How to rewrite this code, such that PyCharm doesn't warn Local variable might be referenced before assignment?

Tags: python, pycharm, warnings

Please consider

```
def foo():
    bs = (4, 5)
    for b in bs:
        c = b + 1
    return c
```

PyCharm marks the `c` in the `return c` with

> Local variable 'c' might be referenced before assignment

This is a good warning, usually, and I don't want to disable it. (`#noqa` is not an answer)

In this case, however, it can be deduced before running that c always has a value.

---

How to rewrite the code to help PyCharm understand this?

Comment: what's the point of that loop? it looks like nonsense as you're going to consider only the last value. Remove the loop and write `c = bs[-1] if bs else 0`

Comment: I guess the point of that loop is to build a MWE, I hope he does more stuff in the loop and wants to return the final value of something that is computed at each iteration

Comment: It can be deduced only by analyzing `bs`, from `c`'s perspective it's not safe. Giving `c` a default value saves the code in case bs changes.

Comment: @endive1783 of course this is a [mre]. No other point in doing things like that :) And yes, this arises from an inherent design flaw I can't fix right now

Answer (score 1):

You can do what is done in most languages which is to instantiate c to a value of 0.

```
def foo():
    bs = (4, 5)
    c = 0     
    for b in bs:
        c = b + 1
    return c
```